# Sequential Scripts conditioned by S3 file existence

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have three python scripts. These are supposed be executed sequentially, but in different environments.

- script1: Generate training and test dataset using an AWS EMR cluster and save it on S3.
- script2: Train a Machine Learning model using the training data and save the trained model on S3. (Executed on an AWS GPU instance)
- script3: Run evaluation based on the test data and trained model and save the result on S3. (Executed on an AWS GPU instance)

I would like to run all these scripts automatically, without executing them one by one. My questions are:

- Are there good practices for handling S3 file existence conditions? (false tolerence etc)
- How can I trigger launching GPU instances and EMR clusters?

Are there good ways or tools to handle this kind of process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

You can configure your notification when an event occur on a bucket, for example when an object is created.

You can attach this notification directly to an AWS lambda function that, if will be set with the right role can create EMR cluster and all other resources accessible by AWS SDK.